# Rhino ETL supports which database?

Tags: rhino, rhino-etl

I was choose to integrate Rhino ETL tool in my application.

In my application i am using various databases like sql server, oracle, mysql, sybase, Informix, db2, ingress.

Will Rhino support these databases and which ones?

And also can I migrate ienumerable< row > to a datatable?

If possible,  how? I am looking for generic method.

Thanks for your guidance to integrate the Rhino ETL tool.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, with the **InputCommandOperation**, you can use any database there is an [ADO.NET Data Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dd363565.aspx) for.  Outside of that, you can implement the **AbstractOperation** to load any data that you can figure out how to load within .NET.